# Twitter Bootstrap - Stop container resizing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, resize, containers, fixed

How do i stop bootstrap elements from resizing with the browser?

So when I change the width of my browser, the container and the navbar stays the same width?

I googled a lot but i just couldn't find the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about using bootstrap and stopping a `div` with a class of `container` from resizing,  Make sure you **are not** using `bootstrap-responsive.css`. This should fix that problem.

If you are talking about html element in general, you need to add `height` and `width` css to each of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the responsive feature of Bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive